# How to use 'use' in php , Getting fatal error

Tags: php, namespaces

I have learned that I need to use name space in php like I have used in my following code but I'm getting `Fatal error: Trait 'SuperClosure\Serializer' not found`
I have used it like this:

```
use SuperClosure\Serializer;
public function set( $key, $value )
   {
    $key = strtolower( $key );      
    $serializer = new Serializer();
    $serialized = $serializer->serialize($value);



    $_SESSION["HA::STORE"][$key] = $serialized;
   }
```

where I am wrong ? please tell me the correct way to use it?

Comment: chould be that the SuperClosure\Serialize need another path .. check where is placed in your dir  scaffolding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use namespaces before declaring class because word `use` point to `Trait` mechanism ([PHP: Traits](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)). Example of namespaces and traits in class:

```
<?php namespace Foo\Bar;

/* I am telling to PHP compiler that class
 * Serializer has different path than class Baz.
 */
use SuperClosure\Serializer;
use SuperClosure\Shortcuts;

class Baz {
    /* Now I used Trait. That should include
     * methods defined in trait Shortcuts
     */
    use Shortcuts;
}
```

Also I recommend read more about [namespaces](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php) and [importing](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php) them.